# Android Tablet Devices for development that support os rebuilding and loading

Tags: android, operating-system, tablet, rebuild

I am looking for a Android tablet device that will permit me to modify, rebuild and reload the Android operating system in a fashion similar to what Google provides developers with the Nexus One phone.  Are there any tablets out there that officially support this kind of development cycle?

Thanks for your help,

Patrick Keith-Hynes

Answer (score 0):

Motorola Xoom ([Reference](http://www.androidcentral.com/motorola-xoom-have-unlockable-bootloader-developers))